# Flutter: A value of type 'ListTileThemeData' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'ListTileTheme'

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter2.0

I am posting this question to help future readers.  After upgrading to `Flutter 2.8` I suddenly got this error when trying to run my app:

```
Flutter: A value of type 'ListTileThemeData' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'ListTileTheme'.
```

How did I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out this error was caused by a popular library I used (`settings_ui`) that does not work with this version of Flutter (`settings_ui: ^1.0.0`).

---

**For future readers:** Use a later version of this package. There is currently an open issue on [github](https://github.com/yako-dev/flutter-settings-ui/issues/102) that addresses this.

Update 2022: **Dev on settings_ui seems to have gone AWOL and no longer merging PR's** the community has forked this project to: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_settings_ui and here updates are properly merged and a fix has been released in version 1.0.1

---

**For people facing this issue now:**

As a monkey patch you can follow the steps in the GitHub issue and edit the package files locally:

In `cupertino_settings_item.dart`
change `final ListTileTheme tileTheme = ListTileTheme.of(context);` to `final tileTheme = ListTileTheme.of(context);`

And change `_iconColor(ThemeData theme, ListTileTheme tileTheme)` to `_iconColor(ThemeData theme, ListTileThemeData tileTheme)`.

Answer (score 2):

Update flutter_settings_ui: ^2.0.1 to latest and save.

import 'package:flutter_settings_ui/flutter_settings_ui.dart';

Save and flutter run solves this issue.

Comment: Please explain the effect of this and why it solves the problem.

Comment: Older version settings_ui: ^1.0.0 doesn't support it. That's why we need to update to the latest flutter_settings_ui: ^2.0.1
Hence it solves the issue.

Comment: Ok. Now do the explaining within your answer, to improve it. You can [edit].

Comment: I had to switch from settings_ui to flutter_settings_ui to make it work.